# PHP - How to loop through array of objects and sum values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ContractorID] => 7049             //<- REMOVE
            [ContractorName] => Supermarket 1  //<-REMOVE
            [SpendAmount] => 615.36            //<-SUM OF ALL ELEMENTS WHERE GroupID IS THE SAME
            [BonusAmount] => 24.61             //<-SUM OF ALL ELEMENTS WHERE GroupID IS THE SAME
            [GroupID] => 1                     //<- RETAIN
            [GroupDescription] => Supermarkets //<- RETAIN
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ContractorID] => 11233
            [ContractorName] => Supermarket 2
            [SpendAmount] => 858.74
            [BonusAmount] => 34.35
            [GroupID] => 1
            [GroupDescription] => Supermarkets
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ContractorID] => 19393
            [ContractorName] => Car repair shop 1 
            [SpendAmount] => 386.79
            [BonusAmount] => 15.47
            [GroupID] => 2
            [GroupDescription] => Automotive
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ContractorID] => 19868
            [ContractorName] => Mike's Autos
            [SpendAmount] => 364.81
            [BonusAmount] => 14.59
            [GroupID] => 2
            [GroupDescription] => Automotive
        )

 )
```

I want to end up with an array that looks like this:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [SpendAmount] => 1474.1
            [BonusAmount] => 58.96
            [GroupID] => 1
            [GroupDescription] => Supermarkets
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [SpendAmount] => 751.6
            [BonusAmount] => 30.06
            [GroupID] => 2
            [GroupDescription] => Automotive
        )
)
```

Where `BonusAmount` is the total of all elements `BonusAmount` and `SpendAmount` is the total of all elements `SpendAmount`.

The summing is simple enough in and of itself, but what I am struggling with is how to retain the `GroupID` and `GroupDescription` as I loop through the elements.

Could anyone give me an idea of how I should "retain" the `GroupID` and `GroupDescription` syntactically and create an element in my resultant array based on the `GroupID`? All help much appreciated.

Comment: Someone needs to read manuals.

Comment: @u_mulder Is that your contribution to an honest question?

Comment: @j your question `Could anyone give me an idea`. My idea - __read a manual__.

Comment: @u_mulder  Congratz.  You win the Sheldon Cooper award.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used `array_walk_recursive`, but `array_walk` or even a simple `foreach` would suffice.

```
//Recreate input data from question
$in = [
        (object) [
            'ContractorID' => '7049',
            'ContractorName' => 'Supermarket 1',
            'SpendAmount' => '615.36',
            'BonusAmount' => '24.61',
            'GroupID' => '1',
            'GroupDescription' => 'Supermarkets',
        ],
        (object) [
            'ContractorID' => '11233',
            'ContractorName' => 'Supermarket 2',
            'SpendAmount' => '858.74',
            'BonusAmount' => '34.35',
            'GroupID' => '1',
            'GroupDescription' => 'Supermarkets',
        ],
        (object) [
            'ContractorID' => '19393',
            'ContractorName' => 'Car repair shop 1 ',
            'SpendAmount' => '386.79',
            'BonusAmount' => '15.47',
            'GroupID' => '2',
            'GroupDescription' => 'Automotive',
        ],
        (object) [
            'ContractorID' => '19868',
            'ContractorName' => 'Mike\'s Autos',
            'SpendAmount' => '364.81',
            'BonusAmount' => '14.59',
            'GroupID' => '2',
            'GroupDescription' => 'Automotive',
        ]
];

//For each object in the array $in, add the object details to a new array.
$return = [];
array_walk_recursive($in, function($a) use (&$return) {
    $found = false;
    //Does this group exist in the array? If so - add spendamount and bonus amount to group.
    foreach($return as $group) {
        if($group->GroupID== $a->GroupID) {
            $found = true;

            $group->SpendAmount += $a->SpendAmount;
            $group->BonusAmount += $a->BonusAmount;

            break;
        }
    }

    //Group not found - create it.
    if(!$found) {
        $return[] = (object) [
            'SpendAmount' => $a->SpendAmount,
            'BonusAmount' => $a->BonusAmount,
            'GroupID' => $a->GroupID,
            'GroupDescription' => $a->GroupDescription,
        ];
    }
});

var_dump($return);
/*
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[6]
      public 'SpendAmount' => float 1474.1
      public 'BonusAmount' => float 58.96
      public 'GroupID' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'GroupDescription' => string 'Supermarkets' (length=12)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[7]
      public 'SpendAmount' => float 751.6
      public 'BonusAmount' => float 30.06
      public 'GroupID' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'GroupDescription' => string 'Automotive' (length=10)
*/
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, sir.  I will attempt this and let you know what happens.

Comment: This works perfectly, AND I learned something.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

One way of solving this would be to loop through the array of objects checking which ones you've already had and which ones you haven't yet. An example of how to do this is as followed:

```
        $results = [];
        foreach($objects as $object){
            if(isset($results[$object->GroupID])){
                $results[$object->GroupID]->SpendAmount += $object->SpendAmount;
                $results[$object->GroupID]->BonusAmount += $object->BonusAmount;
            }else{
                $results[$object->GroupID] = [
                    'SpendAmount' => $object->SpendAmount,
                    'BonusAmount' => $object->BonusAmount,
                    'GroupDescription' => $object->GroupDescription
                ];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can traverse the array and sum the items, **[live demo](https://eval.in/816904)**.

```
 $r = [];
 foreach($array as $v)
 {
 @$r[$v->GroupID]->SpendAmount += $v->SpendAmount;
 @$r[$v->GroupID]->BonusAmount += $v->BonusAmount;
 @$r[$v->GroupID]->GroupID = $v->GroupID;
 @$r[$v->GroupID]->GroupDescription = $v->GroupDescription;
 }
 print_r(array_values($r));
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not an array but an object and hence they are treated differently http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

You access object by `$obj->field_name`

and you can loop through the object as such

```
$result = [];
foreach($object as $obj) {
   $result[] = $obj->field1 + $ojb->field2;
}
```

Comment: Actually, it is an array of objects.  The question pertains to how to "flatten" the array based on certain keys in the object, whilst retaining a sum of certain values.